# Transfer of complete databases in Mysql (WAMP)

Tags: mysql, database, wamp, data-transfer

I am working in a project heavily involving WAMP. The complete size of all the databases on the Mysql server in WAMP is around 150 mb. How do I transfer this between computers ? There seems to be a limit on the size of the file. Altering PHP MyAdmin doesn't seem to help.

Also, I usually import databases individually by creating a database with the same name and then selecting the database file to be imported. However, I have now exported all the databases collectively and it gave me a file called localhost.sql (With 8 databases in it)

How do I import this in a Mysql server in another computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use PHPMyAdmin. Instead use [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) utility to create a dump file:

```
mysqldump --user=root --all-databases > dump.sql
```

This will create a `dump.sql` with all databases on your server. For information on how to select individual databases/tables see the [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html)

Then on another computer load the dump into mysql

```
mysql --user=root < dump.sql
```